# CFHTMLTOPDF/CFDOCUMENT - Envelope Printing - CSS Transform

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Been dealing with this issue forever, hopefully someone has some insight.

Trying to print an envelope via CFDOCUMENT/CFHTMLTOPDF with CSS transformed text, rotated 90 degrees to print in portrait format.

I'm using the following code to setup my portrait oriented envelope, and I'm doing this because the printers I have to use don't allow for printing a business envelope in landscape format, this is the only way I can load the envelope.

I have tried just outputting the envelope without using CFDOCUMENT, just rendering it via CF, but then the printer is erroring out trying to print it.

I know CFDOCUMENT only allows CSS1/2, so transform doesn't work. I found it apparently also doesn't work in CFHTMLTOPDF, so does anyone have any ideas?

```
<cfhtmltopdf pagetype="custom" pagewidth="4.125" pageheight="9.5">
<div style="margin-top: 200px; transform: rotate(90deg);">
envelope content here
</div>
</cfhtmltopdf>
```

Thanks in advance!

T

Comment: What does your webpage look like when viewed using Chrome (or QtWeb, the rendered using by CFHTMLTOPDF)?  If I use your provided inline CSS, I don't see the text on the webpage... so I'm not how it would be rendered in the PDF. Do you have a better HTML sample that works in Chrome/QtWeb?

Comment: It looks as expected, with the text/content 200 pixels down on the page, aligned to the left side. The transform property is ignored.

Comment: Have you tried WKHTMLTOPDF instead?  Apparently it doesn't have the same limitations while also respecting print CSS.

Comment: NOTE:  This isn't an ACF issue.

I use WKHTMLTOPDF and I test the HTML/CSS using QtWeb to ensure that it renders the way I expect it to.  It looks like it doesn't work as the text isn't rotated when rendered using the QtWeb browser (available at QtWeb.net) I generate lots of envelopes too. I even use a USPSIMB webfont.  We rotate PDFs when printing so we don't have to generate rotated text. (Even if you do rotate the text, it doesn't look very good in the browser.)